# Can we get database dumps?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Anton over at MO regularly releases database dumps, which are great if you want to search through everything (including comments), or go statistic-hunting (e.g. compare the frequencies of certain words to gauge interests). Is there a way we could get something like that here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume public dumps will be made regularly available once Math.SE leaves beta. Once Math.SE (and perhaps MO) become full SE 2.0 sites, you can explore their databases using the awesome [SE data explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/). For example, you can see that about [a third of my answers on SO have been accepted](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/96/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate?UserId=104142)

Comment: Cool. Thanks. (And extra characters.)

Answer (score 12):

You will see database dumps for Mathematics.SE starting with the November 2010 SE database dump, which will probably be released within the next few days. The reason they have not been available yet is that Mathematics.SE did not exit beta before the October 2010 database dump, which is a requirement to be included.

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/)?

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [Anton's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/710/can-we-get-database-dumps/711#711):

Jeff Atwood [commented on the StackOverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/creative-commons-data-dump-jul-10/#comments)

> We generally wait 4-6 months until a site has enough data to be useful.

referring to the [cc data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) that already exist for StackOverflow/ServerFault/SuperUser.
As I understand it, the Data Explorer tool Anton mentioned is based on these database dumps. It doesn't pull anything from the live StackOverflow database.

See this [question on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/when-will-stackexchange-sites-be-available-in-data-explorer).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of the dumps that SO/etc. did and the Data Explorer, or I would have searched for that first.

Answer (score 6):

Bump!

Now it is past 4-6 months and database dumps should be given out.