# How do I know I won't lose all my work in math.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, export

Lately I've been wondering if it was remotely possible that my questions and answers (or any other user's) got lost by any kind of malfunction. Is there some kind of backup that ensures all the great answers and question made by users in math.SE is safe? Is it possible to "back-up" certain questions or answers in some easy and effortless manner? As an example, take Brian or André's, *+5000* answers.

Comment: I've made a [similar question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/what-will-happen-if-mse-or-se-in-general-be-closed-someday).

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Should have looked before asking. Though my question is more about the existence of a trustful back-up.

Comment: Yes. Your question is different, It just reminded me of my question. Didn't want to classify it as a dupe.

Comment: There are public database dumps that you can download and backup on your own hard drive on occasion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170405/options-for-community-data-dump

Comment: Use SinglePage widget in Chrome to save any important page to an upload folder (synced from time to time to an internet storage center e.g. skydrive or ubuntuone).

Comment: @AsafKaragila How does that work?

Answer (score 10):

Well, there's an [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/). It has a bookmarklet and a greasemonkey script that can be used to easily print a virtual copy of a question. The only problem is that the only output I've seen from this printer is uglier than me, I'm unaware of how to configure it to a nicer output.

There are also virtual printers such as:

- Nitro PDF Creator;
- PDFill;
- Universal Document Conversor;
- Cute PDF

As Asaf commented, there are public database dumps, Mad Scientist points it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4980/25805):

> SE provides a database dump of all graduated sites every few months,
>   you can use that to set up a copy of this site if you like. For every
>   site that was shut down (only beta sites have been shut down, no
>   graduated sites), SE provided a final data dump with all the site
>   content.

With some scripting software, I guess you can make an automated database backup. [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/710/25805) adds a few more details. [These queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/queries?q=backup) in Stack Exchange Data Explorer can export all your questions/answers in a CSV file.

Comment: what do you mean with uglier than me?

Comment: [Look](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=math.stackexchange&printer=false&question=151938), I still dunno if it's possible to configure to a visually pleasing version.

Comment: It's a stripped version for printing on a printer, what do you expect :)?

Comment: I tried to print and got the same thing - but on paper.